# Cloudflare secondary name server timeout

Tags: domain-name-system, mx-record, cloudflare

I recently switched over to Cloudflare and some people have problem sending mail. I've checked and double checked my DNS settings and they look right. However, I have found that querying the secondary nameserver gives a timeout, which I suspect may be the cause of this disruption.

My question then: Is this indeed an issue with Cloudflare or is it expected that I can only reach one of the NS?

Nameservers are:

- derek.ns.cloudflare.com
- jamie.ns.cloudflare.com

Querying them:

```
$ dig @derek.ns.cloudflare.com domain.com

; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> @derek.ns.cloudflare.com domain.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 64539
;; flags: qr aa rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;domain.com.            IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
domain.com.     300 IN  A   108.162.206.18
domain.com.     300 IN  A   108.162.205.18

;; Query time: 32 msec
;; SERVER: 173.245.59.154#53(173.245.59.154)
;; WHEN: Tue Oct  7 13:22:26 2014
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 64
```

and the secondary:

```
$ dig @jamie.ns.cloudflare.com domain.com

; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> @jamie.ns.cloudflare.com domain.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

### Just a quick update:

I contacted cf support on this, but they couldn't replicate on their end, so that didn't help much. They did point out that my mx records were slightly different from Google Apps recommendation (That must have changed that at some point), but those were just backup record 4+5, so hardly the main reason for this outage. I finally switched ns back to Route 53 (Amazon's dns) and shortly after the mail issue was resolved.

In conclusion, either I misconfigured cloudflare somehow or there is an issue with their ns, causing mail not to be delivered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is a issue with Cloudflare.
You should contact them.

Note that this shouldn't case an outage like you described.
If a NS server is unreachable clients *should* query the other one automatically.

Comment: Thanks. It only happens for some senders - not all, so maybe their mail servers only look up on one of the servers. Any idea how common that error would be?

Comment: Hard to say, there are many DNS implementations out there. Maybe not all handle that case correctly.